# Asyncio Update interface with values from API

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, python-asyncio

I am trying to update a interface with values returned from an API. Each new item in the interface corresponds to a call to the API, and I am using a 0.1 seconds delay between calls to the API.

I am using the following methods to perform the calls:

```
async def get_from_url(self, session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        return resp.status

async def get_from_ids(self, ids):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for _id in ids:
            url = self.api_url_template.format(_id)
            params={
                'format': 'image',
                'version': 'normal'
            }
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.get_from_url(session, url))
            tasks.append(task)
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
```

And getting the values with:

```
items = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(downloader.get_from_ids(ids))
```

I have tried creating an async generator but I cannot figure out how to get the values one by one and update the interface.
How would be the right way to implement that? Would asyncio be the right option?

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: This solution waits all tasks to complete before returning the values, I would like to get the values one by one as soon as they get ready.

Comment: Couldn't you simply update the API from inside `get_from_url`?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html). [That looks like what you ask for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamWriter.write).